# Word doesn't appear after compiling

Tags: errors

[image: Picture 1]

So the problem here is that the word I type at line 119 (for those who can read Chinese characters, it's the word "潟") doesn't come out on the right after compiling. The missing Chinese character should appear next to the highlighted character, but I've tried compiling a few times and the problem still persists.

It also isn't a problem of spacing, I've tried putting the "潟" character at the beginning of other lines (or for this case, everywhere!), but when I compile the word just doesn't appear. For everyone's information, I use the package \usepackage{CJK}. So, is it a problem with the package? Or the compiler just can't understand that character?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Probably the character set used by CJK does not contain 潟. You could try to use XeLaTeX which is able to typeset chinese directly (without the `CJK` package or the `\begin{CJK}\end{CJK}` environment), see https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Chinese#xeCJK_with_XeLaTeX for an example.

Comment: Does the log file contain any warning message?  A character that isn't in the font should be reported.

Comment: re: barbara beeton: There isn't any warning in the log file.

Comment: Remark about how the site works: if you want Barbara to get a message about your reply then you should write the 'at' symbol followed by her username, i.e., @barbarabeeton.

Comment: Some really important information is missing from your screenshot. What encoding you are using? What font you are using? What options do you pass to CJK? There are more than 20 ways things can go wrong.